# Problem with package Revise and distributed loop

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, distributed

So I want to do some calculations and therefore want to parallelize a loop.
I'm using the package Revise to apply changes I make in my code.
This works fine if I restart my complete julia session after I change something.

I have tried some different options and simplified my problem but I can't find a solution.

I created the following module:

```
module ParallelTester

using Distributed
export paralleltest

function paralleltest()
    @sync @distributed for i in 1:100
        println("Hi there!")
    end
end

end
```

when I start my julia session I do the following:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(3)
push!(LOAD_PATH, pwd())
@everywhere using Revise, ParallelTester
```

when I run the function `paralleltest()` the result prints as expected.

when I now change the output from `Hi there!` to `Hi there again!`, I get this error:

```
ERROR: On worker 2:
UndefVarError: ##5#6 not defined
deserialize_datatype at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:1115
handle_deserialize at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:771
deserialize at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:731
deserialize_datatype at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:1139
handle_deserialize at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:771
deserialize at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:731
handle_deserialize at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:778
deserialize_msg at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:731
#invokelatest#1 at .\essentials.jl:742 [inlined]
invokelatest at .\essentials.jl:741 [inlined]
message_handler_loop at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\process_messages.jl:160
process_tcp_streams at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\process_messages.jl:117
#105 at .\task.jl:259
#remotecall_fetch#149(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Distributed.Worker, ::Distributed.RRID, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\remotecall.jl:379
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Distributed.Worker, ::Distributed.RRID, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\remotecall.jl:371
#remotecall_fetch#152(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Int64, ::Distributed.RRID, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\remotecall.jl:406
call_on_owner at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\remotecall.jl:406 [inlined]
wait(::Future) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\Distributed\src\remotecall.jl:500
sync_end(::Array{Any,1}) at .\task.jl:213
(::getfield(Distributed, Symbol("##167#169")){getfield(Tester, Symbol("##5#6")),UnitRange{Int64}})() at .\task.jl:245
Stacktrace:
 [1] sync_end(::Array{Any,1}) at .\task.jl:226
 [2] macro expansion at .\task.jl:245 [inlined]
 [3] parallelTest() at C:\Users\FelixMeyer\AppData\Local\Julia-1.1.1\Tester.jl:9
 [4] top-level scope at none:0
```

What am I missing?

I found this [docspage](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl/blob/master/docs/src/limitations.md) of the Revise package and it says that such an error might occur with anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to put the "guts" of `paralleltest` in a separate function:

```
function paralleltest(rng)
    @sync @distributed for i in rng
        paralleltestcore()
    end
end

paralleltestcore() = println("Hi there!")
```

But it would be nice to fix this. There may be a way to do it if we lower the code on the main process and then send the lowered code to each process for evaluation. Meanwhile I've added this case to https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl/issues/147.

Comment: thank you for the information. That workaround is easier than I expected.
I solved the problem by using pmap instead. Going to look into the runtime results.

Comment: Update: with Julia 1.3 and Revise 2.3.2, even the original test case should work now.